# How do I set the button text in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have included this in the html

```
<!-- Bootstrap UI stuff -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and then in my javascript I have tried making the buttons nice by going

```
        $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">',{
            id:"opener-add-"+tableName,
            html:"Add"
            }).appendTo("#form-"+tableName);
```

What I end up with is a blue button but the "Add" is missing (it was the same with anormal button, I lost the text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML and text are not really DOM attributes (you are in effect running: `document.body.setAttribute('html', 'Add')`), you have to set them using the `text` or `html` methods:

```
$('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">',{
            id:"opener-add-"+tableName,
     }).text('Add').appendTo("#form-"+tableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tryt this,

```
$('<button type="button"  id="opener-add-'+tableName+'" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>').appendTo("#form-"+tableName);
```